# Alternatives to $readmemh in Verilog

Tags: verilog

I'm trying to load values from a file into a two-dimensional array like this.

```
 reg  [31:0] RAM[63:0];
 initial
      $readmemh("memory.dat",RAM);
```

What are the alternatives? If I wanted to hardcode the values stored in the memory instead, what's the code to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to hardcode the values, just assign to each memory location:

```
initial begin
    RAM[0] = 32'h1234_5678;
    RAM[1] = 32'h9abc_def0;
    RAM[2] = 32'haaaa_5555;
    // etc.
end
```

Another alternative to `$readmemh` is to use the file IO system tasks, such as `$fopen` and `$fscanf` (refer to the IEEE Standard or your simulator documentation).